# JGraphX : "InvalidDnDOperationException: Drag and drop in progress" when using Swing Node in JavaFX

Tags: java, swing, javafx, drag-and-drop, jgraphx

I want to use JGraphX with JavaFX, but I have a little problem.
Using this code :

```java
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import org.jgrapht.ListenableGraph;
import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultDirectedGraph;
import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultEdge;
import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultListenableGraph;

import com.mxgraph.swing.mxGraphComponent;
import com.mxgraph.view.mxGraph;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App4 extends Application {

    ListenableGraph<String, DefaultEdge> g = new DefaultListenableGraph<>(
            new DefaultDirectedGraph<>(DefaultEdge.class));

    mxGraph graph = new mxGraph();
    Object parent;
    mxGraphComponent graphComponent = new mxGraphComponent(graph);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws InterruptedException {
        final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
        createSwingContent(swingNode);
        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        pane.getChildren().add(swingNode);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 450, 100);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Nodes");
        stage.show();
    }

    private void createSwingContent(final SwingNode swingNode) throws InterruptedException {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                graph.insertVertex(parent, "", "Node", 0, 0, 60, 60);
                swingNode.setContent(graphComponent);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

The following exception is thrown when I'm dragging a Node in the window.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.dnd.InvalidDnDOperationException: Drag and drop in progress
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDragSourceContextPeer.setDragDropInProgress(SunDragSourceContextPeer.java:358)
    at java.awt.dnd.DragSource.startDrag(DragSource.java:301)
    at java.awt.dnd.DragSource.startDrag(DragSource.java:396)
    at java.awt.dnd.DragGestureEvent.startDrag(DragGestureEvent.java:292)
    at com.mxgraph.swing.handler.mxGraphHandler$3.dragGestureRecognized(mxGraphHandler.java:298)
    at java.awt.dnd.DragGestureRecognizer.fireDragGestureRecognized(DragGestureRecognizer.java:361)
    at sun.awt.windows.WMouseDragGestureRecognizer.mouseDragged(WMouseDragGestureRecognizer.java:218)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseDragged(AWTEventMulticaster.java:320)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseMotionEvent(Component.java:6587)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseMotionEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6308)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4552)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:188)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at javafx.embed.swing.FXDnD$FXDragSourceContextPeer.startDrag(FXDnD.java:360)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDragSourceContextPeer.startDrag(SunDragSourceContextPeer.java:135)
    at java.awt.dnd.DragSource.startDrag(DragSource.java:321)
    at java.awt.dnd.DragSource.startDrag(DragSource.java:396)
    at java.awt.dnd.DragGestureEvent.startDrag(DragGestureEvent.java:292)
    at com.mxgraph.swing.handler.mxGraphHandler$3.dragGestureRecognized(mxGraphHandler.java:298)
    at java.awt.dnd.DragGestureRecognizer.fireDragGestureRecognized(DragGestureRecognizer.java:361)
    at sun.awt.windows.WMouseDragGestureRecognizer.mouseDragged(WMouseDragGestureRecognizer.java:218)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseDragged(AWTEventMulticaster.java:320)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseMotionEvent(Component.java:6587)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseMotionEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6308)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4552)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I tried to use it with :
`SwingUtilities.InvokeLater([...])` or without, but it didn't changed anything.

It seems that there is collision between both JavaFX and Swing event queues but I have no idea how to solve this.

I'm using Java 8 and here is the dependencies i'm using for JGraphX :

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jgrapht</groupId>
            <artifactId>jgrapht-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tinyjee.jgraphx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jgraphx</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jgrapht</groupId>
            <artifactId>jgrapht-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jgrapht</groupId>
            <artifactId>jgrapht-ext</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

was looking for the same thing for a few days, try using

```
graphComponent.setDragEnabled(false);
```

that fixed the problem for me